# Can I set a char or DateTime to null?

Tags: c#

Can I set null into `char` data type? and also `DateTime` in C#? thanks guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is impossible, it is a value type. Use

```
char? myChar = null;
DateTime? myDate = null;
```

which is equivalent to

```
Nullable<char> myChar = null;
Nullable<DateTime> myDate = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. These are value types and cannot be `null`.

However, you could use `char?` and `DateTime?` instead. The `?` makes a type nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Nullable<> generic:

```
Nullable<char> myChar = null;
Nullable<DateTime> myDate = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have C# 2.0 or newer, you can use Nullable types, like so:

```
char? myChar = null;
myChar = 'a';
// Do whatever you want with myChar
```

And the same goes for DateTime, just add a question mark after the type.

Answer (score 0):

They can't actually be null because they are value types, you could set a char to 0 and a DateTime to DateTime.MinValue. Or you could set them to default(char), default(DateTime). Or use a Nullable type and you could have an actual null.