# how to set DBnull value for char

Tags: c#, char, dbnull

I am working on application in that fetching record from database.but when fetching char datatype of value is null then it shows error.
here is my Code:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            lstServiceCall_Activity.Add(new OpportunityActivity()
            {
                Recontact = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["Recontact"]) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Recontact"]),
                endDate = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["endDate"]) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["endDate"]),
                Details = (reader["Details"]) == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToString(reader["Details"]),
                Location = (reader["Location"]) == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["Location"]),
                CardCode = (reader["CardCode"]) == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToString(reader["CardCode"]),
                Action = Convert.ToChar(reader["Action"]),
                Priority = Convert.ToChar(reader["Priority"]),
                CntctType = Convert.ToChar(reader["CntctType"]),
                assignedTo = Convert.ToString(reader["AttendUser"])
            }
            );
        }
```

for char how to set dbnull value.
Please give some suggestion.

Comment: char is a value type. Cannot be set to null, [and then follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812904/can-i-set-a-char-or-datetime-to-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Action  = (reader["Action"]) == DBNull.Value ?'\0' : Convert.ToChar(reader["Action"]),
```

Use like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a `char` to `null`, so you either have to make it nullable by adding a `?` after `char`, or use the null-terminator as an identifier for an 'empty' character:

```
char? canBeNull = null;

char nullTerminated = '\0';
```

Which option you choose is up to you, but I would option 1, since that makes clear what your intentions were with this variable.

So the end result would be something like this:

```
char? Priority = reader["Priority"] != DBNull.Value
                 ? Convert.ToChar(reader["Priority"])
                 : (char?)null;
```

Comment: He did ask specifically for DBNull, which leaves the only option as declaring it as object.

Comment: He reads it from a `SqlDataReader`, which makes the need to convert a `DBNull.Value` to something useful.